# How do I auto expire messages that dont have a consumer?

Tags: activemq-classic

I need the broker to delete all messages that dont have any consumers waiting. I seem to recall that this should be a default behavior, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approcahes to define a time-to-live for ativeMQ messages,if in this time period message is not consumed then it will expire.

you can have two approaches for this

```
producer.setTimeToLive(Long timeToLiveInMilliSeconds)
```

Above approach will apply to all messages from this producer or if you want for specific messages you can do it like this

```
producer.send(Destination destination,Message message,int deliveryMode,int priority,long timeToLive)
```

apart from this,there is no default configuration that message gets deleted as soon as it is placed on a queue and there is no consumer for that queue

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: hm strange, I must have misremembered that behavior. Yes I knew about the time to live, but I guess I would like a feature where if there is no open tcp connection to a consumer on the broker side, it should discard that message for that queue immediately.